# Should I convert this method's queries to Stored Procedures?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, stored-procedures

At my job the other devs have spent a lot of time converting their sql queries to stored procs. Personally, I thought it made sense since a lot of those queries were complicated and joined many tables. I on the other hand, haven't written such complex queries, so I thought it would be fine to stick w EF/Linq. However on my latest pr, my lead highlighted one of my methods and said it should be converted to a stored proc. I disagree, since it's extremely simple, but he's technically I lead so I want other eyes on it, maybe he's right. Here is the method in question:

```
 public static List<FormFieldPropertyHistoryViewModel> GetFieldPropertyHistory(int? formFieldId)
        {
            List<FormFieldPropertyHistoryViewModel> history = new List<FormFieldPropertyHistoryViewModel>();
            List<dbo_FormFields_CT> fields = new List<dbo_FormFields_CT>();

            using (var ctx = new Entities())
            {
                fields = ctx.dbo_FormFields_CT.Where(f => f.ID == formFieldId).ToList();
            }

            foreach (var row in fields)
            {
                var ffhvm = new FormFieldPropertyHistoryViewModel();
                switch (row.FieldType)
                {
                    case "TEXTBOX":
                        using (var ctx = new Entities())
                        {
                            var textboxHistory = new FormFieldTextBoxPropertyHistoryViewModel(); 
                            var textboxfield = ctx.dbo_FormFieldsTextBox_CT.Where(f => f.FormFieldsID == formFieldId && f.C___operation == row.C___operation && f.C___start_lsn == row.C___start_lsn).FirstOrDefault();
                            textboxHistory.DateEdited = row.DateAdded;
                            textboxHistory.EditedBy = row.CreatedBy;
                            textboxHistory.Label = row.Label;
                            textboxHistory.IsRequired = row.IsRequired;
                            textboxHistory.IsSystemField = row.IsSystemField;
                            textboxHistory.IsAssessmentField = row.IsAssessmentField;
                            textboxHistory.Hint = row.Hint;
                            textboxHistory.HelpText = row.HelpText;
                            textboxHistory.UniqueField = row.UniqueField;
                            textboxHistory.RegexField = row.RegexField;
                            if (textboxfield != null)
                            {
                                textboxHistory.MaxCharacters = textboxfield.MaxCharacters;
                            }

                            textboxHistory.IsPassword = row.IsPassword;
                            textboxHistory.IsWikiSearch = row.IsWikiSearch;
                            history.Add(textboxHistory);
                        }
                        
                        break;
                    case "TEXTAREA":
                        using (var ctx = new Entities())
                        {
                            var textareaHistory = new FormFieldTextAreaPropertyHistoryViewModel();
                            var textboxfield = ctx.dbo_FormFieldsTextBox_CT.Where(f => f.FormFieldsID == formFieldId && f.C___operation == row.C___operation && f.C___start_lsn == row.C___start_lsn).FirstOrDefault();
                            textareaHistory.DateEdited = row.DateAdded;
                            textareaHistory.EditedBy = row.CreatedBy;
                            textareaHistory.Label = row.Label;
                            textareaHistory.IsRequired = row.IsRequired;
                            textareaHistory.IsSystemField = row.IsSystemField;
                            textareaHistory.IsAssessmentField = row.IsAssessmentField;
                            textareaHistory.HelpText = row.HelpText;
                            textareaHistory.RegexField = row.RegexField;
                            if (textboxfield != null)
                            {
                                textareaHistory.MaxCharacters = textboxfield.MaxCharacters;
                                textareaHistory.IsEditable = textboxfield.isEditable;
                                textareaHistory.IsRichTextBox = textboxfield.isRichTextBox;
                            }
                            history.Add(textareaHistory);

                        }
                        break;
                    case "CHECKBOX":
                        var checkboxHistory = new FormFieldCheckboxPropertyHistoryViewModel();
                        checkboxHistory.DateEdited = row.DateAdded;
                        checkboxHistory.EditedBy = row.CreatedBy;
                        checkboxHistory.Label = row.Label;
                        checkboxHistory.IsRequired = row.IsRequired;
                        checkboxHistory.IsSystemField = row.IsSystemField;
                        checkboxHistory.IsAssessmentField = row.IsAssessmentField;
                        checkboxHistory.HelpText = row.HelpText;
                        history.Add(checkboxHistory);
                        break;
                    case "DROPDOWNLIST":
                        var dropdownHistory = new FormFieldDropDownPropertyHistoryViewModel();
                        dropdownHistory.DateEdited = row.DateAdded;
                        dropdownHistory.EditedBy = row.CreatedBy;
                        dropdownHistory.Label = row.Label;
                        dropdownHistory.IsRequired = row.IsRequired;
                        dropdownHistory.IsSystemField = row.IsSystemField;
                        dropdownHistory.IsAssessmentField = row.IsAssessmentField;
                        dropdownHistory.HelpText = row.HelpText;
                        dropdownHistory.HoverText = row.HoverText;
                        dropdownHistory.Options = row.Options;
                        dropdownHistory.SelectedOption = row.SelectedOption;
                        dropdownHistory.AllowUserValues = row.AllowUserValues;
                        dropdownHistory.UniqueField = row.UniqueField;
                        history.Add(dropdownHistory);
                        break;
                    case "RADIOBUTTON":
                        var radioHistory = new FormFieldRadioPropertyHistoryViewModel();
                        radioHistory.DateEdited = row.DateAdded;
                        radioHistory.EditedBy = row.CreatedBy;
                        radioHistory.Label = row.Label;
                        radioHistory.IsRequired = row.IsRequired;
                        radioHistory.IsSystemField = row.IsSystemField;
                        radioHistory.IsAssessmentField = row.IsAssessmentField;
                        radioHistory.HelpText = row.HelpText;
                        radioHistory.Options = row.Options;
                        radioHistory.SelectedOption = row.SelectedOption;
                        history.Add(radioHistory);
                        break;
                    case "CALCULATEDFIELD":
                        using (var ctx = new Entities())
                        {
                            var calcFieldHistory = new FormFieldCalculatedPropertyHistoryViewModel();
                            var calcfield = ctx.dbo_FormFieldsCalculatedField_CT.Where(f => f.FormFieldsID == formFieldId && f.C___operation == row.C___operation && f.C___start_lsn == row.C___start_lsn).FirstOrDefault();
                            calcFieldHistory.DateEdited = row.DateAdded;
                            calcFieldHistory.EditedBy = row.CreatedBy;
                            calcFieldHistory.Label = row.Label;
                            calcFieldHistory.IsRequired = row.IsRequired;
                            calcFieldHistory.IsSystemField = row.IsSystemField;
                            calcFieldHistory.IsAssessmentField = row.IsAssessmentField;
                            calcFieldHistory.Hint = row.Hint;
                            calcFieldHistory.HelpText = row.HelpText;

                            if (calcfield != null)
                            {
                                calcFieldHistory.Formula = calcfield.Formula;
                            }

                            calcFieldHistory.CurrencyType = row.CurrencyType;
                            calcFieldHistory.TimeZone = row.TimeZone;
                            history.Add(calcFieldHistory);
                        }
                      
                        break;

                    case "LOOKUP":
                        using (var ctx = new Entities())
                        {
                            var lookupFieldHistory = new FormFieldLookupPropertyHistoryViewModel();
                            var lookupfield = ctx.dbo_FormFieldsLookupList_CT.Where(f => f.FormFieldsID == formFieldId && f.C___operation == row.C___operation && f.C___start_lsn == row.C___start_lsn).FirstOrDefault();
                            lookupFieldHistory.DateEdited = row.DateAdded;
                            lookupFieldHistory.EditedBy = row.CreatedBy;
                            lookupFieldHistory.Label = row.Label;
                            lookupFieldHistory.IsRequired = row.IsRequired;
                            lookupFieldHistory.IsSystemField = row.IsSystemField;
                            lookupFieldHistory.IsAssessmentField = row.IsAssessmentField;
                            lookupFieldHistory.Hint = row.Hint;
                            lookupFieldHistory.HelpText = row.HelpText;
                            lookupFieldHistory.EnableAddNew = row.EnableAddNew;
                            lookupFieldHistory.UniqueField = row.UniqueField;


                            if (lookupfield != null)
                            {
                                lookupFieldHistory.LookupList = lookupfield.LookupList;
                                lookupFieldHistory.LookupColumns = lookupfield.LookupColumns;
                                lookupFieldHistory.LookupAdditionalColumns = lookupfield.LookupAdditionalColumns;
                            }

                            history.Add(lookupFieldHistory);
                        }

                        break;
                    case "ADDRESS":
                    case "PHONE":
                        var addressHistory = new FormFieldAddressPropertyHistoryViewModel();
                        addressHistory.DateEdited = row.DateAdded;
                        addressHistory.EditedBy = row.CreatedBy;
                        addressHistory.Label = row.Label;
                        addressHistory.IsRequired = row.IsRequired;
                        addressHistory.IsSystemField = row.IsSystemField;
                        addressHistory.IsAssessmentField = row.IsAssessmentField;
                        addressHistory.HelpText = row.HelpText;
                        history.Add(addressHistory);
                        break;
                    case "EMAIL":
                        var emailHistory = new FormFieldEmailPropertyHistoryViewModel();
                        emailHistory.DateEdited = row.DateAdded;
                        emailHistory.EditedBy = row.CreatedBy;
                        emailHistory.Label = row.Label;
                        emailHistory.IsRequired = row.IsRequired;
                        emailHistory.IsSystemField = row.IsSystemField;
                        emailHistory.IsAssessmentField = row.IsAssessmentField;
                        emailHistory.MaxChars = row.MaxChars;
                        history.Add(emailHistory);
                        break;
                    case "DATEPICKER":
                    case "BIRTHDAYPICKER":
                        var datepickerHistory = new FormFieldDatePickerPropertyHistoryViewModel();

                        datepickerHistory.DateEdited = row.DateAdded;
                        datepickerHistory.EditedBy = row.CreatedBy;
                        datepickerHistory.Label = row.Label;
                        datepickerHistory.IsRequired = row.IsRequired;
                        datepickerHistory.IsSystemField = row.IsSystemField;
                        datepickerHistory.IsAssessmentField = row.IsAssessmentField;
                        datepickerHistory.HelpText = row.HelpText;
                        datepickerHistory.TimeZone = row.TimeZone;
                        history.Add(datepickerHistory);
                        break;
                    case "FULLNAME":
                        var fullNameHistory = new FormFieldFullnamePropertyHistoryViewModel();
                        fullNameHistory.DateEdited = row.DateAdded;
                        fullNameHistory.EditedBy = row.CreatedBy;
                        fullNameHistory.Label = row.Label;
                        fullNameHistory.IsRequired = row.IsRequired;
                        fullNameHistory.IsSystemField = row.IsSystemField;
                        fullNameHistory.IsAssessmentField = row.IsAssessmentField;
                        fullNameHistory.HelpText = row.HelpText;
                        fullNameHistory.UniqueField = row.UniqueField;
                        history.Add(fullNameHistory);
                        break;
                    case "FILEPICKER":
                        using (var ctx = new Entities())
                        {
                            var fileFieldHistory = new FormFieldFilePropertyHistoryViewModel();
                            var filefield = ctx.dbo_FormFieldsFileUpload_CT.Where(f => f.FormFieldsID == formFieldId && f.C___operation == row.C___operation && f.C___start_lsn == row.C___start_lsn).FirstOrDefault();
                            fileFieldHistory.DateEdited = row.DateAdded;
                            fileFieldHistory.EditedBy = row.CreatedBy;
                            fileFieldHistory.Label = row.Label;
                            fileFieldHistory.IsRequired = row.IsRequired;

                            fileFieldHistory.HelpText = row.HelpText;



                            if (filefield != null)
                            {
                                fileFieldHistory.AllowedFileExtensions = filefield.AllowedFileExtensions;
                                fileFieldHistory.MinFileSizeInMB = filefield.MinFileSizeInMB;
                                fileFieldHistory.MaxFileSizeInMB = filefield.MaxFileSizeInMB;
                            }

                            history.Add(fileFieldHistory);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;

                }

                
            }

            return history;
        }
```

Comment: Forget the proc! The switch is code smell. I'd refactor that. Look into conditional to polymorphism.

Comment: Do what your lead developer says.   On my current project, there is no EF, EVERYTHING is a stored proc, even the extremely simple stuff.  That's the lead developers choice, you should be consistent with the rest of the project.

Comment: There's no SQL or stored procedures above. How could we know if the conversions are fine...?

Comment: I suggest asking them why. They may have good reasons, or they may not, or they may have bad reasons. In the last two scenarios, they may be open to discussing the pros and cons of stored procedures, or they may just say (effectively) "do it this way". So: we can't answer "should I" questions. You presumably could, and it may or may not be a good idea to do so. Whether to use stored procedures (or not) is very much a contextual decision, and we lack your context.

Answer (score 1):

There are some considerations here, both pro and con your position.

**Firstly**,

> I disagree, since it's extremely simple

This code is by no means simple. It is in *dire* need of refactoring, because it is massively bloated and nigh unmaintainable. It is way too monolithic, on top of it being switch-branched and deeply nested.

This is a textbook OCP violation and is in dire need of needing to separate its constituent branches into individual components.

Regardless of stored procs or not, this code should not pass any reasonable code review.

**Secondly**,

> At my job the other devs have spent a lot of time converting their sql queries to stored procs.

I generally consider moving from EF to stored procedures to be moving in the wrong direction. While there are (rare) fringe cases where stored procs are more suited to a specific use case than EF's in-code query syntax is, I'm hard-pressed to find any case in which you should *blanket* move to sprocs, as opposed to using EF and occasionally relying on a sproc where relevant.

If all devs are converting their queries to stored procs, that sounds like it's *well* beyond a reasonable fringe exceptional use case and is delving into the field of architectural archaeology.

**Thirdly**,

> I on the other hand, haven't written such complex queries, so I thought it would be fine to stick w EF/Linq.

Although I'm no proponent of sprocs by any measure, you shouldn't go rogue either. A consistent but archaic codebase is still better than a codebase with a collage of different approaches and implementations where every developer does their own thing.

---

Distilling these considerations into the best advice possible:

- At all times, ensure consistency between developers. No matter the choices being made.
- While stored procedures aren't an impossible implementation, they are at the very least an outdated approach. There is definitely room for some discussion to be had with the lead developer, to re-evaluate if sprocs are the right approach.

  - However, that re-evaluation may have already happened and you simply weren't included in the decision-making process.
  - Based on the question as written, it is impossible for me to judge whether your lead dev is making a bad blind call, or whether they have actually genuinely evaluated their options and you simply didn't present the full picture in your question.
  - Without trying to be mean, based on the code you presented and calling it simple, I infer that you are a junior developer, and you are unlikely to be a voice with equal weight compared to your lead dev and possibly some of your coworkers. I very much doubt that your input is going to sway anyone unless you come up with some concrete evidence that is not subjective.
- If all else fails, it's still worth talking to your lead dev to at least understand their reasoning. Not as an entry point to arguing why they are wrong, but rather to understand where they are coming from and why they're choosing this approach. Even if you can't change their mind, it's a good learning opportunity, and maybe in future projects where you *will* get some sort of say, you will be more able to make a balanced judgment call.

Answer (score 0):

Put a method on your DbContext to encapsulate this query and use that.  eg

```
public IList<FormField> GetFormFieldsById( int formFieldId )
{
  var fields = this.dbo_FormFields_CT.Where(f => f.ID == formFieldId).ToList();
  return fields;
}
```

Then if you, your lead, or some other dev wants to implement a stored procedure to hold this logic, your code doesn't have to change.

But you shouldn't have to jump over to some other tool and start writing queries in some other language to complete this feature.

Comment: "to complete this feature" is not the be all end all goal here. Consistency in the codebase is an important factor beyond "it works", and OP mentioned that there has been a general shift towards sprocs by their coworkers. I'm not a fan of sprocs by any means, but I'm even less of a fan of fragmented codebases with a patchwork of implementations and styles.

Comment: My point is that you can do both.  Start with a LINQ query encapsulated in your DbContext, then replace it with a stored procedure if you want.  This also enables someone else to create the stored procedures.

Comment: The last paragraph seems to very much favor one approach over the other though. It suggests that you _shouldn't_ have to move over to sprocs. Which I don't completely disagree with, but with the notable caveat of consistency within the dev team.